# Setting byte[] to SQL prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am setting an SQL prepared statement like this:

```
prd.setBytes(i+1, temp_value);
```

Where temp_value is of type byte[].

At the end i am adding the prd statement to a batch like this:

```
prd.addBatch();
prd.executeBatch();
```

The executeBatch gives me the exception: 
**java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Error converting data type varbinary to numeric.**

Is it possible to simply add Bytes to a prepared statement no matter if the field in the DataBase table is of type Numeric or any other type?

Do i have to be speccific about the type i am inserting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setBytes` method is intended for use with SQL BLOB types, such as `varbinary`, `longvarbinary`, and so on. For the numeric types you need to use `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`, or a numeric primitive.

The issue with allowing `setBytes` to be used with non-binary types is system independence: you would need to match the driver's expected layout for a multi-byte number with potentially vey complex structure that JDBC driver writers would need to publish. Once this layout is published, their driver would have to remain compatible with it for life. Most driver writers, however, would prefer to avoid such tight coupling with the client code.

Answer (score 1):

Appendix B (Data Type Conversion Tables) in the JDBC 4.1 specification lists all conversions that a JDBC driver must implement (for supported types). Specifically table B-4 lists a mapping Java Object Types to JDBC Types and table B-5 lists a conversion matrix for `setObject()`. For `byte[]`, a JDBC driver is only required to support conversion to/from `BINARY`, `VARBINARY` and `LONGVARBINARY`.

So based on the JDBC specification you cannot use `setBytes()` for other datatypes. There are drivers that will allow using `setBytes()` for other types as well, but as that is driver specific you should not depend on that conversion. The error message you receive makes perfectly clear that your driver simply doesn't support this conversion.

Also specifically for a `NUMERIC` type you should wonder how you could represent it in a `byte[]` sequence that is valid for your specific database.